# How to check which type of access user has (Nodejs and mongodb)

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am creating an alarm tracking management system for the remote smart devices. Using nodejs and mongodb. The idea is like this when the device has the alarm I want that the user who has permission could see the alarm error (or history of errors) after he logs in. Let say I have three types of user, first type can track only one group of devices, second another group and third all devices. For the demo version I am thinking to create a user in my mongodb and add the array with the 3 types of devices group and assign true of false to each device group depending on the access urer have. I already have log in system, but I want some advise how to check if the user has access to group one then he can be redirected after login to particular route and etc. What I think create a function that checks somehow 'if(user nameOfgroup1 is true) then redirect to nameOfgroup1 view' but not sure how to write code for this condition. My user schema:

```
    var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    local: {
        username: String,
        password: String,
        access:[{

        nameOfgroup1: String,
        available: Boolean
    },
    {   
        nameOfgroup2: String,
        available: Boolean

   }, 
   {    
        nameOfgroup3: String,
        available: Boolean

   }]}});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be simpler to store an array of group IDs that the user should have access to. That way you'll be able to easily add more groups in the future and also checking for a given group would be easy.

For example, if the user's doc in the DB would be something like:

```
{ "username" : "name", "groups" : [ 0, 2 ] }
```

then it's easy to check which groups he has access to but also to check a specific group with:

```
function check(user, group) {
  return user.groups.indexOf(group) > -1;
}
```

Also it's easy to search for users with access to a given group in the database:

```
db.users.find({groups:2});
```

Instead of numbers you can use names or ObjectIds or whatever is convenient for you.